# swing avoid rewriting jframe options

Tags: java, swing, oop

Well,I have a lot of `JFrames` on my program and I don't want to code `setSize(),setResizable(),setVisible etc.`all the time.

So How can I avoid doing that, I cannot extend because of I already extended Jframe how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is not a reason for extending JFrame. You should extend a class when you add functionality. Invoke methods of the class is not adding functionality.

Comment: Mind telling us why you have a lot of JFrames?

Comment: `I have a lot of JFrames on my program and I don't want to code setSize(),setResizable(),setVisible etc`. == `CardLayout` with `JFrame.pack()` after card is switched

Comment: @mKorbel As I recall, `pack()` after switching cards doesn't adjust size to panel being shown. I remember `CardLayout` sizing the frame based off the biggest panel in the deck. I don't completely remember though, haven't used it personally in a while and no access to a computer at the moment

Comment: pack doesn't work as excepted,when I use it, my frames size is like 20,20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's discouraged to extend general purpose classes like `JFrame`, a part from the fact that you are not adding any additional functionality to the frame (you're just configuring it), you could also lock yourself into a given implementation, reducing the re-usability of your components, instead,

## You could...

Use a "factory" pattern to generate a utility class which did the work for you....

```
public class FrameFactory {
    public static JFrame createFrameWithTitle(String title) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        return frame;
    }

    public static JFrame createNonResizableFrameWithTitle(String title) {
        JFrame frame = createFrameWithTtitle(title);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        return frame;
    }
    //...
}
```

## You could...

Use a "builder" pattern...

```
public class FrameBuilder {

    private String title;
    private int closeOperation;
    private boolean resizable;

    public FrameBuilder() {
        closeOperation = JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;
        resizable = false;
    }

    public FrameBuilder setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        return this;
    }

    public FrameBuilder setDefaultCloseOperation(int op) {
        this.closeOperation = op;
        return this;
    }

    public FrameBuilder setResizable(boolean resizable) {
        this.resizable = resizable;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public boolean isResizable() {
        return resizable;
    }

    public int getCloseOperation() {
        return closeOperation;
    }

    public JFrame build() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getTitle());
        frame.setResizable(isResizable());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(getCloseOperation());
        return frame;
    }

}
```

This would allow you to define a "common" series of properties, which could be modified via one or more of the chained methods to provide a level of customisation...

```
JFrame frame = new FrameBuilder().
        setTitle("Test").
        setResizable(true).
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE).
        build();
```

Answer (score 0):

create `YourCustomJframe` and set everything in its constructor and `extend` it or just create instance of it

Comment: uhm,first one is make perfect sense but second one I didn't get it what do you mean by create instance of it ?

Comment: `new YourCustomJframe()`

Comment: It's generally discouraged to extend `JFrame` for a number of reasons, it might be better to use a factory or builder pattern instead

Comment: curious, why it is discouraged ? and yes extend and use builder sounds better

Comment: @JigarJoshi Generally speaking you are not actually adding any new functionality to the class, you're just providing a custom configuration, which could be achieved using a factory or builder pattern.  This locks you into a particular implementation, if you know want to change it slightly for a limited use case, would you provide ANOTHER extension or simply configure that use case independently? What if you wanted to use a different window? Extension also locks you into a implementation, limiting your potential reuse (this won't be easy to port to applet for example)

Comment: I see your point, Builder is definitely better tool here, I would still create `VisibleFrame` and add Builder on top of it

Comment: @JigarJoshi Think about this, you builder could be capable of building `JFrame`, `JDialog` and/or `JWindow`...so it really shouldn't extend from any of these classes, just saying...